# How to back up router firmware before flashing

Tags: router, firmware

I have just bought a `TP-Link TL-WR841N` router and would like to flash it with 
a different firmware, e.g. [openwrt](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/walkthrough_flash). I would like to do the same with an old router I do not use any more.

Question: Is it possible to create a backup image of the currently installed firmware from the router so that I can restore it later if I want to? I haven't found any specific documentation on this.

Comment: The easier way is to download the current firmware image from the TP-Link homepage, and use that as a backup image. Alternative: Get into the uboot loader (google), and see if it can transfer out an image via tftp (but I haven't tried this).

Comment: @dirkt: Thanks. I haven't found any information as to how to get to the `uboot` loader. I will keep googling for it.